# Python - kill multiple processes in a function

Tags: python, process, kill, psutil

I'm new to python, and have the following code working to kill processes, 
but it's not elegant.
 I have to define the process and the search for it on multiple lines .

I'm looking to create a function or a way to assign any process I add to this list,  and kill all with out looking for each one. (its  seems redundant )

something like assigning any new PROCESS I add,  to be in a method  ALL_PROC and then the for loop can iterate over it, looking for any and all processes contained in ALL_PROC

sorry if this is obvious , this is my first stack question :)

```
Process1 = "pro1.exe"
Process2 = "pro2.exe"
Process3 = "pro3.exe"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():  
    if proc.name() == Process1:
       proc.kill()
    if proc.name() == Process2:
       proc.kill()
    if proc.name() == Process3:
       proc.kill()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a set of names, then you can check presence with the `in` operator:

```
processes = {'pro1.exe', 'pro2.exe', 'pro3.exe'}
for proc in psutil.process_iter():  
    if proc.name() in processes:
       proc.kill()
```

---

And if you wanted to define a set of the first `n` `'pro[n].exe'` strings, then you could use a generator expression with the `set()` constructor:

```
processes = set(f'pro{i}.exe' for i in range(1,n))
```

which, with e.g. `n = 10`, gives:

```
{'pro6.exe', 'pro8.exe', 'pro9.exe', 'pro2.exe', 'pro4.exe', 'pro3.exe', 'pro1.exe', 'pro7.exe', 'pro5.exe'}
```

*notice that a set does not have order, since it has no concept of indexes.*

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks, that was fast! and exactly what i was looking for.   not sure I fully understand the second part,  but hopefully will one day soon. ( I upvoted fyi, but im new so it doesnt show)

Comment: @montystack read [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to understand the second syntax better :) oh and you can accept the answer which does give me some rep (even though you don't have any) :p